# User Input to File

Tags: c, file, text, io

I'm creating a program that should create a structure of a list of people entered by the user; the only problem I'm having is getting the user input data to appear in the text file. Anyone know how to do this? Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct person{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    struct person *next_ptr;
    } PERSON;

int main (void){


struct person PERSON;

FILE *fp;
char ans, ch;
int ppl=0;

fp=fopen("person_struct", "w");

if(fp != NULL){

while(ppl<25){


printf("Would you like to add a person to the list? [y/n]  ");
scanf("%c", &ans);

if(ans == 'y') {
    printf("\nEnter a name:\n");
    scanf("%s", PERSON.name);
    fprintf(fp, "%s",PERSON.name);  
    printf("\nEnter age:\n"); 
    scanf("%i", &PERSON.age);
    fprintf(fp, "  %i\n", PERSON.age);
} 
else {
  ppl=25;       
}

ppl++;
}
fclose(fp);
}   
printf("\n\n\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Youe scanf statement is wrong you forgot ampersand `&` operator before `PERSON.age` its int

```
scanf("%i", PERSON.age);
           ^ & missing
```

correct is:

```
scanf("%i", &PERSON.age);
```

You have two scanf stamens in your code to inputs from user one for string to scan name.

```
scanf("%s", PERSON.name);
```

This is correct and No need of `&` before string. But age is `int` and to scan int.float you need to add `&` before variable that is why added ampersand `&` before PERSON.age. 
ref: [scanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fscanf.html)

**Second:**

`fputs(PERSON.age, fp);` is wrong syntax of fputs is:

```
int fputs( const char *str, FILE *stream );
                   ^ you are passing int
```

first argument should be `const char*` but your are passing `int`

```
fputs(PERSON.age, fp);
       ^ wrong , age is int not char*
```

When you need formatting input/output prefer printf and scanf functions,  My suggestion change your read/write like: (*read comments*)

```
printf("Enter a name:\n"); 
scanf("%s", PERSON.name);  // here is No & because `name` is string 
scanf("%i", &PERSON.age);  // age is `int` so & needed 
fprintf(fp,"%s %i\n",PERSON.name, PERSON.age);
```

**EDIT**:  Because you commented, your code is working after these rectifications, see

```
$ gcc x.c -Wall
$ ./a.out 
Would you like to add a person to the list? [y/n]y
Enter a name:
yourname
14
Would you like to add a person to the list? [y/n]y
Enter a name:
firendName
15
Would you like to add a person to the list? [y/n]n
sh: 1: pause: not found
$ cat person_struct.txt
yourname 14 
firendName 15
```

Comment: ... and why is an ampersand required? If you're going to explain this, make sure you explain it entirely so that people don't get confused and start adding ampersands before PERSON.name in `scanf("%s", PERSON.name);`, which is already a pointer. A less redundant way to go about this would be to link to [the scanf manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fscanf.html) and ask "Which type corresponds to the `%i` format specifier?".

Comment: Still doesn't work; when I added the ampersand, the program crashed after entering the age.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Yes you are correct I should add this is important here

Comment: @user2184761 you need to add `&` before age only not infornt of name

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Can you add my answer to yours (perhaps in your own words), so I can delete mine and vote up yours? :D

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I would like vote your contribution :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Grijesh's answer:

Please explain `scanf("%s", &ans);`. How many characters can you store in ans? How many characters does the string "y" require to store? Verify your beliefs: `printf("sizeof ans: %zu\n" "sizeoof \"y\": %zu\n", sizeof ans, sizeof "y");`

Perhaps you meant: `if (scanf("%c", &ans) != 1) { /* assume stdin has closed or reached EOF */ }`. Note the `%c`, which *will read only one character into ans*.

Alternatively, if you change ans to an `int`, you can use: `ans = getchar();`

edit: In short, I think your loop should look something like this:

```
for (size_t ppl = 0; ppl < 25; ppl++){
    int ans;

    printf("Would you like to add a person to the list? [y/n]");
    do {
        ans = getchar();
    while (ans >= 0 && isspace(ans));

    if (ans != 'y') {
        break;
    }

    printf("Enter a name:\n");
    if (scanf("%s", PERSON.name) != 1 || scanf("%i", &PERSON.age) != 1) {
        break;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s %i\n", PERSON.name, PERSON.age);
}
```

Comment: If I change scanf("%s", &ans); to scanf("%c", &ans), the loop will only go through once.

Comment: @user2184761 Well, at least `scanf("%c", &ans)` isn't undefined behaviour. Why do you suppose the loop only goes through once? Do you think it's because ans contains something that isn't 'y'? What character is that? Do you think when you encounter whitespace such as `'\n'` (eg. `isspace(ans)`), you might need to `continue;` to loop again?

Comment: @user2184761 don't add `&` in front of string.

Comment: I've got it to copy to the file, however, it only loops once, if I change the %c back to %s, it will loop up to 25 times, but it won't print to the file. The edited code is pasted over the previous code.